# Saving changes of very simple model in admin view fires several errors on GoogleComputeEngine, WHY?

Tags: django, utf-8, google-compute-engine, django-wsgi, litespeed

I have an `OpenLiteSpeed Django` app in `Google Cloud Compute Engine` which connects a `SQLite` DB. I've created some models and views, in those views I can show lists and graphics of SQLite data. I am also able to list and search the data in admin views. However in admin view when I try to make some changes and save or delete mostly get `500 Internal Error`, it works rarely.

Model that I try to make changes:

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):

    aciklama = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I cannot debug on server, to see errors I check `stderr.log` file in project directory.
Following errors occur when I get `500 Internal Error` on admin view page:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 7: invalid continuation byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'lsapi_wsgi.Request'> returned a result with an error set
Not Found: /favicon.ico
2020-05-16 06:31:45.902022 [ERROR] [1643] wsgiAppHandler failed to create req_obj.
```

If there is a way to debug on compute engine please share with me.

Btw on my local environment it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, please turn DEBUG = True in django and restart web server see what's the output

Comment: Hi, it's already `True`, but deployed project gives only `500 Internal Error`. That's why i check `stderr.log` file.

Comment: ok, if you can run django build-in server(runserver) without issue, please submit issue to support@litespeedtech.com for diagnosis